# Javascript modal page function "Undefined" problem

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a web page and trying to implement a simple modal page with javascript. What I'm doing is to define JS function `onClick(element)` that read the attribute values of the element and pass them to target elements that are on the modal page.

And I made the function called when a specific element is clicked by adding an attribute `onclick="onClick(this)"`.

The function is working just fine except all parts like `element.SOMETHING` return "Undefined".
How can I fix this???

- Here is button div

```html
      <div
        class="acw3-quarter acw3-panel acw3-padding-16"
        onclick="onClick(this)"
        product_name="{{product.name}}"
        sub_category="{{subs.name}}"
        category="{{category.name}}"
        description="{{product.description}}"
        i0="{{ product.image_main.url }}"
        {% if product.image_1 %}
        i1="{{ product.image_1.url }}"
        {% endif %}
        {% if product.image_2 %}
        i2="{{ product.image_2.url }}"
        {% endif %}
        {% if product.image_3 %}
        i3="{{ product.image_3.url }}"
        {% endif %}
        {% if product.image_4 %}
        i4="{{ product.image_4.url }}"
        {% endif %}
        {% if product.image_5 %}
        i5="{{ product.image_5.url }}"
        {% endif %}
      >
```

- This is modal div

```html
  <div
    class="acw3-modal-content acw3-animate-zoom acw3-center acw3-transparent acw3-padding-64"
  >
    <h2 id="category"></h2>
    <h3 id="sub_category"></h3>
    <img id="img0" class="acw3-image" />
    <h4 id="product_name" class="acw3-opacity acw3-large"></h4>
    <p id="description"></p>
    <img id="img1" class="acw3-image" />
    <img id="img2" class="acw3-image" />
    <img id="img3" class="acw3-image" />
    <img id="img4" class="acw3-image" />
    <img id="img5" class="acw3-image" />
  </div>
```

- And finally, this is the JS function.

```html
  function onClick(element) {
    document.getElementById("img0").src = element.i0;
    document.getElementById("img1").src = element.i1;
    document.getElementById("img2").src = element.i2;
    document.getElementById("img3").src = element.i3;
    document.getElementById("img4").src = element.i4;
    document.getElementById("img5").src = element.i5;

    var categoryText = document.getElementById("category");
    var subsText = document.getElementById("sub_category");
    var nameText = document.getElementById("product_name");
    var descriptionText = document.getElementById("description");

    categoryText.innerHTML = element.category;
    subsText.innerHTML = element.sub_category;
    nameText.innerHTML = element.product_name;
    descriptionText.innerHTML = element.description;

    document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  }
```

Here is what these codes rendered.

```html
<div class="acw3-modal-content acw3-animate-zoom acw3-center acw3-transparent acw3-padding-64">
    <h2 id="category">undefined</h2>
    <h3 id="sub_category">undefined</h3>
    <img id="img0" class="acw3-image" src="undefined">
    <h4 id="product_name" class="acw3-opacity acw3-large">undefined</h4>
    <p id="description">undefined</p>
    <img id="img1" class="acw3-image" src="undefined">
    <img id="img2" class="acw3-image" src="undefined">
    <img id="img3" class="acw3-image" src="undefined">
    <img id="img4" class="acw3-image" src="undefined">
    <img id="img5" class="acw3-image" src="undefined">
  </div>
```

Oh, and I checked that Django template parts(`{%  %}`) are working just fine; they are substituted to what they should be. It seems like just JS functions can not read the values with `element.SOMETING`.

Comment: Attributes are not necessarily properties. Use `getAttribute`.

Comment: if you use `data-product_name="{{product.name}}"` then you can use `element.dataset.product_name` etc - adding `data-*` attributes is more in keeping with HTML standard than random attributes

Comment: open the devtools in your browser with f12 and choose the "console" tab. There you can enter your JS code one line at a time. Enter there `document.getElementById('foo')`. It will show you that dom element, which you can inspect and look what properties it has

Comment: Good points. Problem solved. Thank you all ^^